# mysql asking twice for password even though it was already provided

Tags: mysql, bash

I have this script:

```
read PASS
mysql -u root -p "$PASS" < myfile.sql
```

If I already provided the password, why am I getting a second prompt to enter the password for mysql?

Comment: FYI: If it's a password, you probably want `read -s PASS`.

Comment: Try `mysql -u root -p"$PASS" < myfile.sql`.  According to `man mysql`: If you use the short option form (`-p`), you **cannot** have a space between the option and the password.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax is either:

```
mysql -u root -p"$PASS" < myfile.sql
```

with no space after `-p` or:

```
mysql -u root --password="$PASS" < myfile.sql
```

The explanation for the first syntax is in the [Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/command-line-options.html). For most options, the space between the option and its value is optional. But it says:

> An exception to this rule is the option for specifying your MySQL password. This option can be given in long form as --password=pass_val or as --password. In the latter case (with no password value given), the program prompts you for the password. The password option also may be given in short form as -ppass_val or as -p. However, for the short form, if the password value is given, it must follow the option letter with no intervening space. The reason for this is that if a space follows the option letter, the program has no way to tell whether a following argument is supposed to be the password value or some other kind of argument.

Comment: I was just about to post this as a comment after noticing it in the man page :-)

Comment: I am still asked for the password

Comment: I don't believe you. I tried it myself before posting the answer.

Comment: @dabadaba: This works for me.  On my system I tried http://pastebin.com/y6BidmvH and it works fine.

Comment: what if the password is blank and the user just hits enter

Comment: Or use the long option name. `--password=` will not ask for a password